Exporting a nicematrix figure
I am looking to export a nicematrix figure. My idea was to use the standalone package and then have a transparent background. However, using the standalone package yields an error. First, I obtain "LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." with the figure environment, and additionally, I have "Fatal Package nicematrix Error: Outside math mode."
If I were to change the document class to "article", everything works fine. I have included a MWE where the error occurs, though I have only tried this in overleaf.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\let\proglang=\textsf
\let\code=\texttt
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{5.5pt}  % Horizontal length
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}  % Vertical height
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
    first-col,
  ]
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & \Hdotsfor{10} & a_{1,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{2,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{2, 20} & \\
\text{\small PROD} & \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small CPI} & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{5,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{5,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{6,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{6,20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{9,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{9,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{10,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{10,20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2}& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{13, 1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{13, 20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{14, 1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{14, 20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=brown!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{17,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{17,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{18,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{18,20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2}& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <->}}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
  ]
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{1,1} & \Hdotsfor{10}[line-style = standard] & a_{1,20} & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{USA}} \\
\Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{2,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{2,20}& \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{3,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{3,20} & \\
\Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{4,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{4,20} & \\
\Vdotsfor{12}[line-style = standard] & & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{CAN}} \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{DEU}} \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{FRA}} \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{17,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{17,20} & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{GBR}} \\
\Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{18,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{18,20} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{19,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{19,20} & \\
\Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{20,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{20,20} & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{figure}
\end{document}


This question is similar to: How to make a standalone document with one equation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Start with removing all unnecessary packages. No figure or display math, just $...$ is enough.
The last-col is outside the bounding box, so you have to help standalone and provide an extended border on the right (experiment, with the given setup 1cm seems good).
\documentclass[border={1mm 1mm 1cm 1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\setlength\arraycolsep{5.5pt}  % Horizontal length
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}  % Vertical height

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[
  margin,
  last-col,
  first-col,
]
\text{\small IR}
  & \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & \Hdotsfor{10} & a_{1,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP}
  & a_{2,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{2, 20} & \\
\text{\small PROD} & \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small CPI} & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR}
  & \Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{5,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{5,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{6,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{6,20} & \\
  & \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR}
  & \Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{9,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{9,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP}
  & a_{10,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{10,20} & \\
  & \Vdotsfor{2}& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR}
  & \Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{13, 1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{13, 20} & \\
\text{\small GDP}
  & a_{14, 1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{14, 20} & \\
  & \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR}
  & \Block[fill=brown!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{17,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{17,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP}
  & a_{18,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{18,20} & \\
  & \Vdotsfor{2}& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <->}}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[
  margin,
  last-col,
]
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{1,1}
  & \Hdotsfor{10}[line-style = standard] & a_{1,20} & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{USA}} \\
\Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{2,1}
  & & & & & & & & & & & a_{2,20} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{3,1}
  & & & & & & & & & & & a_{3,20} & \\
\Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{4,1}
  & & & & & & & & & & & a_{4,20} & \\
\Vdotsfor{12}[line-style = standard]
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{CAN}} \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{DEU}} \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{FRA}} \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{}
  a_{17,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{17,20} & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{GBR}} \\
\Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{18,1}
  & & & & & & & & & & & a_{18,20} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{19,1}
  & & & & & & & & & & & a_{19,20} & \\
\Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{20,1}
  & & & & & & & & & & & a_{20,20} & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}



You can use the varwidth option:
\documentclass[varwidth,border={1mm 1mm 10mm 1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\let\proglang=\textsf
\let\code=\texttt
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{5.5pt}  % Horizontal length
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}  % Vertical height
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
    first-col,
  ]
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & \Hdotsfor{10} & a_{1,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{2,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{2, 20} & \\
\text{\small PROD} & \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small CPI} & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{5,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{5,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{6,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{6,20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{9,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{9,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{10,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{10,20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2}& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{13, 1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{13, 20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{14, 1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{14, 20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\text{\small IR} & \Block[fill=brown!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{17,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{17,20} & \\
\text{\small GDP} & a_{18,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{18,20} & \\
& \Vdotsfor{2}& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <->}}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
  ]
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{1,1} & \Hdotsfor{10}[line-style = standard] & a_{1,20} & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{USA}} \\
\Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{2,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{2,20}& \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{3,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{3,20} & \\
\Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{4,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{4,20} & \\
\Vdotsfor{12}[line-style = standard] & & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{CAN}} \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{DEU}} \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{FRA}} \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{17,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{17,20} & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{GBR}} \\
\Block[fill=cyan!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{18,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{18,20} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{19,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{19,20} & \\
\Block[fill=violet!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{20,1} & & & & & & & & & & & a_{20,20} & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
%\end{figure}
\end{document}



You should add \hspace*{1cm} at the end because the arrows and their labels on the right are in an overlapping position...

@F.Pantigny oh, I didn't notice them. Thanks! I changed the border.
